# Incrementing values in a dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary.

```
'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0}
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0}
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0}
'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0}
```

I have the variables speaker and listener. A speaker is the name of the dictionary, and the listener can be one of the keys in the dictionary. For example 'Frank' is the speaker, and 'Jack','Sam' and 'Kevin' could either be a  listener in the first dict created. I want to be able to increment the value for a specific listener. For example if speaker = 'Sam' and listener = 'Kevin', I want this to happen

```
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 1}
```

And vice versa

```
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 1}
```

Programming and python newbie here. Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! I have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
d = {
'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0} }

d ['Frank'] ['Kevin'] += 1

print (d)
```

`d['Frank']` is the listener dictionary of Frank, and `d['Frank']['Kevin']` is how many times Kevin has listened to Frank. This value you can increment.

Or if the speaker-listener relation is symmetrical, you can try this:

```
def talk (speaker, listener, data):
    data[speaker][listener] += 1
    data[listener][speaker] += 1

d = {
'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0},
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0} }

talk('Frank', 'Sam', d)

print(d)
```

Comment: but I think he also wants d['Kevin']['Frank'] +=1

Comment: so for your answer to address OP question should it be for speaker, listener in some iterable d[speaker][listener] +=1, d[listner][speaker] +=1

Comment: @PyNEwbie I suppose that speaking and listening is directional, and he stated "vice versa". Let's leave this to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably create a new `Person` object, to be honest.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def speak(self,other):
        for (speaker,listener) in ((self,other),(other,self)):
            try: speaker.__dict__[listener.name] += 1
            except KeyError: speaker.__dict__[listener.name] = 1
    @property
    def listeners(self):
        return {name:value for name,value in self.__dict__.items() if name != "name"}

## DEMO
>>> Adam = Person("Adam")
>>> Steve = Person("Steve")
>>> Adam.speak(Steve)
>>> Adam.Steve
1
>>> Steve.Adam
1
>>> Paul = Person("Paul")
>>> for listener in [Adam,Steve]:
        Paul.speak(listener)
>>> Paul.listeners
{"Adam":1, "Steve":1}
```

Comment: Let's just hope nobody uses this passing `'name'` to the initializer... or `'speak'`, or any other name of a member of some class that inherits from `Person`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus None of those seem to do anything at all. `Person('foo').speak('name')` will throw an attribute error (trying to access `str.name`) but that's all. In fact if you're REALLY worried about it, you could add an `except AttributeError` to catch invalid input, or require `assert isinstance(other,Person)` etc

Comment: @adsmith More of a `TypeError` than an `AttributeError` if you call a person `'name'`. The snippet `Person('name').speak(Person('Peter'))` raises `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, mimicking @adsmith's answer, but avoiding tampering with `__dict__` and thus making all possible person names permissible.

```
class Person:
    directional = False

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.listeners = {}

    def speak(self, other):
        try: self.listeners[other] += 1
        except KeyError: self.listeners[other] = 1
        if Person.directional: return
        try: other.listeners[self] += 1
        except KeyError: other.listeners[self] = 1

    def __getitem__(self, person):
        try: return self.listeners[person]
        except KeyError: return 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Sample usage:

```
alice = Person('Alice')
bob = Person('Bob')
charles = Person('Charles')

alice.speak(bob)
alice.speak(bob)
bob.speak(charles)

print(alice[bob])
print(alice[charles])
print(alice[bob])
print(bob.listeners)
```